# How to pass -Dproperty from vs code launch configuration?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Hi I run the java background with the below command.

```
exec java -jar -Dproperty.file.path=/home/test/test.properties /home/test/test.jar
```

Is there a  way I can pass the -Dproperty.file.path from vscode launch configuration? this is needed to run the application in debug mode.

Currently I am adding the -Dproperty.file.path in the beginning of main when I have to debug the app but I am looking for a way to pass it from launch configuration.

Comment: The command line used for execution is part of the project properties.  Have you gone through the properties?

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't see a way to get to the project properties in visual studio code, searching online only gets the result for visual studio but not for visual studio code.

Comment: if run with `launch.json` that is the place to add the `-D` argument

Comment: Right.  The `args` field in `launch.json` specifies the command line arguments.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options

Comment: You can pass the command through the args parameter in launch.json

Answer (score 0):

We could use **args** in launch.json to pass information for us.

[image]

Here I copied some of your content as an example. We can directly obtain the parameters passed in **args** in debug mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, It doesn't solve my problem exactly.  I am already doing pretty much the same thing.
`System.setProperty("property.file.path", "<path to file>")`

What I really want is to set a system property from launch.json which can read later anywhere in the code with `System.getProperty("Key")`

Comment: Only the args module can transmit information, but it does not support key-value.